# LNK2001 unresolved external symbol with CPP_XLOPER

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit, xll

I'm migrating a XLL from 32-Bit to 64-Bit with VS2015 and C++.

I started changing the datatypes. So I switched 'int' to '_int64'.

```html
CPP_XLOPER Create_XLOperHeader_form_Str(const wchar_t*aBegin,_int64 strlen,bool aTranspose){
 static CPP_XLOPER xlDefault(L" ");
 _int64 l = strlen;
```

and it throws me the error:

```html
Error 
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol 
"class CPP_XLOPER __cdecl Create_XLOperTable_from_Str(wchar_t const *,__int64,bool,bool)" 
(?Create_XLOperTable_from_Str@@YA?AVCPP_XLOPER@@PEB_W_J_N2@Z)
```

I guess I have to modify 'class CPP_XLOPER', isn't it?

Any hint much appreciated,
thx in advance;
surplus

Answer (score 0):

The method linker is complaining about has last two parameters of type `bool` - `...,int64,bool,bool)`, while the one you have modified has only one last parameter of type `bool`. Either you have deleted another existing method, or you have also removed one `bool` from the implementation (and only you know if this was or was not intentional). But yeah, in general you should fix the function declaration to match the definition.

Comment: Oh. Your are right. I should have seen this.

Thx a lot!

Are you confirm with 32 to 64 Bit migrations?

Cheers surplus